# Row-bind two dataframes, but enforce that the columns' formats of the first dataframe be kept

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'd like to bind (row-wise) two dataframes of different column size, but enforce that the columns' formats of the first dataframe be kept.

Example:

```r
d1 <- tibble(x = 1, y = "b") # before edit: d1 <- tibble(x = 1)
d2 <- tibble(x = c(2, "a"))
```

When employing, say, `plyr`'s `rbind.fill`, the combined column will be of the character type. However, I'd like to obtain the (final) result

```r
str(data.frame(x = c(1, 2, NA)))
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ x: num  1 2 NA
```

I suppose for this to work, I'd have to

- look up `x`'s format in `d1` and then
- force `x` in `d2` to be of the same format, producing `NA`'s along the way, and
- `rbind` thereafter.

The problem is, I cannot come up with an elegant solution to this little problem. Any help will be much appreciated!

*Edited to account for data frames of different column size.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R with `match.fun`:

```r
common <- intersect(names(d1), names(d2))
d2[common] <- lapply(common, function(x) {
  match.fun(paste0("as.", class(d1[[x]])))(d2[[x]])
})

dplyr::bind_rows(d1, d2)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 1
      x
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have mentioned that `d1` has more columns than `d2`. If I construct an example like this, I receive errors: `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'as.NULL' of mode 'function' was not found`
Could you accommodate for this as well...?

Comment: Check edit. Apply the functions only on the common columns. You can't use `rbind` anymore so I changed to `dplyr::bind_rows`

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is reasonable and can be done in a single line:

```r
bind_rows(d1, map2_df(d1, d2, ~ `class<-`(.y, class(.x))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! But I now realize that my MWE was not sufficient, because I receive an error: `Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths`. In my real example, `d1` has more columns than `d2`, and their order differs as well. Could you adjust your approach to allow for this...?